# Maxscript FileIn inside a Custom Attribute

Tags: custom-attributes, maxscript

I have a issues with FileIn() inside a Custom Attribute. Every time I execute my script for the first time I get a undefined class or function. Also I always get the error when I close 3ds max and reopen the scene with my custom attribute on a box.

I hope someone can help me understand what I am doing wrong in my code. I really hope there is a solution because FileIn() is very useful for me to reuse and organize my code. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Here is my code:

```
Global newAttrib = attributes posAttribs
(
fn addFunction FolderName vArray=
(
/*
1)  Get the root position of the installed position of 3ds max
2)  Get in the script file and then in the FolderName of the function
3)  Add all the function inside the vArray in a FileIn Loop
*/
for i = 1 to vArray.count do
(
FolderPosition =  ((GetDir #maxroot)+"\scripts\\" +FolderName + "\\")
FileIn(FolderPosition + vArray[i])
)
)
parameters Param0 rollout:General
(
pPreset0 type:#String ui:ddl_Preset0 default:"..."
pTableHeight type:#Float ui:spn_Height default:100
)--end Param1
parameters Param1 rollout:TopPart
(
pPreset1 type:#String ui:ddl_Preset1 default:"..."
defaultArray1 type:#stringTab tabSize:1 tabSizeVariable:true
defaultExist1 type:#boolean default:False
)--end Param1
parameters Param2 rollout:BottomPart
(
pPreset2 type:#String ui:ddl_Preset2 default:"..."
pLegEndShape type:#String ui:ddl_LegEnd default:"..."
defaultArray2 type:#stringTab tabSize:1 tabSizeVariable:true
defaultExist2 type:#boolean default:False
)--end Param2
parameters Param3 rollout:Supports
(
pPreset3 type:#String ui:ddl_Preset3 default:"..."
defaultArray3 type:#stringTab tabSize:1 tabSizeVariable:true
defaultExist3 type:#boolean default:False
)--end Param3

Local externalFn = #("UI_CaptionChange.ms", "UI_ControlVisible.ms", "UI_MoveVisible.ms")
Local externalMod = #("MOD_Extrude.ms", "MOD_Taper.ms", "MOD_QuadChamfer.ms", "MOD_SweepModifier.ms")
Local TableTypes = sort(#("...", "Dining", "Workbench", "Coffee", "Round"))
Local TopTypes = sort(#("...", "Square", "Rectangle", "Round","Oval","Triangle", "NGon", "Semi Circle", "Quarter Circle"))
Local LegTypes = sort(#("...", "Straight", "Taper", "Cross","U","MultiEnd", "X", "Curve", "T"))
Local LegEndTypes = sort(#("...", "Square", "Rectangular", "Circle","NGon"))
Local SupportTypes = sort(#("...", "CopyTop", "PTP"))
Rollout General "General"
(
dropdownlist ddl_Preset0 "Presets:" items:TableTypes
spinner spn_Height "Height" range:[0,1000,100] type:#float
button btn_Random "Random All" border:True
on General open do
(
addFunction "Mal_Functions" externalFn --Adding all the external function
addFunction "Mal_Modifiers" externalMod --Adding all the external modifiers
ddl_Preset0.selection = findItem ddl_Preset0.items pPreset0
UICaptionChange General 2 "Test"
)
on ddl_Preset0 selected val do
(
pPreset0 = ddl_Preset0.selected
)
)--end TopPart Rollout

Rollout TopPart "Top Part"
(
dropdownlist ddl_Preset1 "Presets:" items:TopTypes
spinner spn_Thickness "Height" range:[0,1000,2] type:#float
spinner spn_Length "Length" range:[0,1000,2] type:#float
spinner spn_Width "Width" range:[0,1000,2] type:#float
on TopPart open do
(
ddl_Preset1.selection = findItem ddl_Preset1.items pPreset1
if defaultExist == False then
(
--defaultArray = UIDefault Testing
--defaultExist = True
)
)
on ddl_Preset1 selected val do
(
pPreset1 = ddl_Preset1.selected
)
)--end TopPart Rollout
Rollout BottomPart "Bottom Part"
(
dropdownlist ddl_Preset2 "Presets:" items:LegTypes
dropdownlist ddl_LegEnd "Leg End Shape:" items:LegEndTypes
on BottomPart open do
(
ddl_Preset2.selection = findItem ddl_Preset2.items pPreset2
ddl_LegEnd.selection = findItem ddl_LegEnd.items pLegEndShape
)
on ddl_Preset2 selected val do
(
pPreset2 = ddl_Preset2.selected
)

on ddl_LegEnd selected val do
(
pLegEndShape = ddl_LegEnd.selected
)
)--end BottomPart Rollout
Rollout Supports "Supports"
(
dropdownlist ddl_Preset3 "Presets:" items:SupportTypes
on Supports open do
(
ddl_Preset3.selection = findItem ddl_Preset3.items pPreset3
)
on ddl_Preset3 selected val do
(
pPreset3 = ddl_Preset3.selected
)
)--end Supports Rollout
)--end posAttribs
modPanel.addModToSelection (EmptyModifier ()) ui:on
custAttributes.add $.modifiers[1] newAttrib --add the attribute in the first modifier
```

Comment: Whats the actual error message?  Does it say which line/item is undefined?  There is nothing technically wrong with what your doing, running FileIn in a loop like this is unusual but not impossible.

Comment: The problems comes from this line:
UICaptionChange General 2 "Test"
The first time I evaluate I get  undefiend function/class but the second time I evaluate my script it works.

Comment: This is the exact message in the Maxscript Listener:
-- Error occurred in General.open(); filename: ; position: 2354; line: 58
--  Frame:
--   UICaptionChange: undefined
>> MAXScript Rollout Handler Exception:
-- Type error: Call needs function or class, got: undefined <<

Answer (score 0):

The function UICaptionChange is not defined in your MaxScript file, so I would guess its in your referenced files?

I'm not 100% sure of this, but my guess is that because maxscript has already parsed the "open" function before executing it, it will have parsed the functino before it runs the FileIn command that defines the new functions.  In other words, your including the functions too late for them to be found.

I would suggest moving your addFunction calls to the global scope just on general principals.  Its very confusing to find code that writes itself in the middle of execution.  Also, you will be re-parsing these included files every time you create/open the attributes, so your paying the cost of recompiling every time.

Just move the code to include the files to the head of your file (in global scope), it will execute only when the script is evaluated, and you should be fine

Comment: When you talk about global scope. Do you mean to put the function addFunction before the Global newAttrib = attributes posAttribs?

If that's what you mean, then how will the attribute holder remember the function the next type I open the 3ds max scene where the custom attribute is use?

Comment: Normally I would stick the definition in the scripts/startups folder

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late response I wasn't home for a couple of days.
I think I did what you said.

I created a startup.ms file taht is locatied in the 3ds max scripts folder.
Inside that file I added my addFunction and then called it righe after by adding ally my other functions that are seperated maxscript file. It's like adding a librairie of function. Right now from what I have seen, its seem to to the trick. Thanks againt with the help. I really apprediate it :)